# Einstein summation convention: What am I missing here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity

Given a Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ and the tensor $h'_{\mu\nu}\equiv h_{\mu\nu} -\frac{1}{2}h'\eta_{\mu\nu}$ (where $h'=\eta^{\mu\nu}h'_{\mu\nu}$), it is claimed that $h'=-h$.

My attempt at proving this goes as: 
\begin{eqnarray}
h' &=& \eta^{\mu\nu}h'_{\mu\nu} \\
&=& \eta^{\mu\nu}\left[ h_{\mu\nu} -\frac{1}{2}h'\eta_{\mu\nu} \right] \\
&=& h -\frac{1}{2}h'\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta_{\mu\nu} \\
&=& h -\frac{1}{2}h'\delta^\mu_\mu \\
&=& h -\frac{4}{2}h' \\
\end{eqnarray}
Which implies $3h' = h$. I am not finding my mistake, but I suspect I'm somehow using the Einstein summation convention wrong. Any help pointing out my mistake would be appreciated.

(I'm working through some lecture notes....$h_{\mu\nu}$ is the perturbation away from Minkowski in linearized gravity.)

Comment: Your definition is incorrect, $h'_{\mu\nu} = h_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2} h \eta_{\mu\nu}$.